# PowerBI Slicer affect only one table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 tables.

Table0 contains the column DateTime0
Table1 contains the columns DateTime1 and Price1.
Table2 contains the columns DateTime2, Price2, and Unit2.

I've linked DateTime0 with DateTime1, and DateTime0 with DateTime2.

I can put in a line plot of Price1 and Price2 as y-axis and DateTime0 as x-axis.
I can put in a slicer of DateTime0, and this then affects my line plot as expected.

I now want to put in a slicer of Unit2, such that Price2 displayed on my line plot would only come from those selected. But If I do this then my Price1 line dissapears, because it is also filtered.

How do I make it so that the slicer only affects the data coming from Table2?

I know I can do this with 2 seperate plots, but I want to be able to do it with one plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [cross filter direction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships#cross-filter-direction) of the relationship between DateTime0 and DateTime2 has the default value of **Both**, while what you want is to be **Single**. Double click the relation (it makes sense to change both relations) and change the value in Cross filter direction combo box to Single:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!
This worked!
For some reason I had to switch it from 1:1 to 1:*, but making the relationship single directional worked!